# Slice url in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using the following url in my template: `{% url 'index' %}`.

Assume that it resolves to `/index`.

How can I slice it? To make it /ind?
`{% url 'index'|slice:"4" %}` doesn't work, it slices index.

Comment: The big question: Why?

Comment: It is just an example. The more general question is how to slice result of applying templatetag.

Comment: slice:2 doesn't work?

Comment: slice:2 slices 'index', not url 'index'. In this case I get no reverse match for 'in'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `as` statement, then apply `slice` or `truncatechars` filters to it

```
  {% url 'index' as the_url %}
  <a href="{{ the_url |truncatechars:4  }}"></a>
```

Comment: It truncates 'index', not url 'index'

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Forgot the {% something as another %} syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
{% with 'index'|slice:":4" as path %}
    {% url path %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: I first need to apply url and then slice, not vice versa.

Comment: what you need? both url ?